# react-admin many-to-many with junction table

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Here is an example of my schema and how i've implemented it in react-admin, can you tell me if is the best way for getting data from a junction table ?

[image: schema]

```
  const Media = () => 
   <ReferenceManyField label="Kiosks" source="id" target="media_id" reference="kiosk_media">
    <SingleFieldList>
      <ReferenceManyField source="kiosk_id" target="id" reference="kiosk">
        <SingleFieldList>
          <TextField source="name" />
        </SingleFieldList>
      </ReferenceManyField>
    </SingleFieldList>
  </ReferenceManyField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I managed it on my back end to follow this structure:
`Kiosk: { id:..., ... Medias:[{id:... },{id:...},{id:...}], ... }`
and then I used ArrayField to display. https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#arrayfield

Comment: Thank you, I know it's possible in this case but I need to keep my junction table

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2:  I figured a way to do this with the free components.  You were close, but you need to use just a plain reference to the final `kiosk` table.  This snippet would show a table of `kiosk` records linked to the current `media` record through the `kiosk_media` table.

```
<ReferenceManyField label="Kiosks" reference="kiosk_media" target="media_id">
  <Datagrid>
    <ReferenceField reference="kiosk" source="kiosk_id" link="show" />
  </Datagrid>
</ReferenceManyField>
```

-- Original Answer --

You can probably use the `ReferenceManyToManyField`.

```
const AuthorShow = () => (
    <Show>
        <SimpleShowLayout>
            <TextField source="first_name" />
            <TextField source="last_name" />
            <DateField source="date_of_birth" />
            <ReferenceManyToManyField 
                reference="books"
                through="book_authors"
                using="author_id,book_id"
            >
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="title" />
                    <DateField source="published_at" />
                </Datagrid>
            </ReferenceManyToManyField>
            <EditButton />
        </SimpleShowLayout>
    </Show>
);
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FieldsForRelationships.html#referencemanytomanyfield

Edit: I just realized that this is a paid Enterprise-only feature, but I'll leave this here for reference.